# HSTACK CNN output with Lambda function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have made one type of `NN` that uses `CNN` and `LSTM` presented [here](https://github.com/rjpg/bftensor/blob/master/Autoencoder/src/RJPGNet.ipynb):

After the `CNN` layers, I use the `Lambda` function to feed each Filter (images created on `CNN`) to one `LSTM`, one-by-one.

Now I want to change this to feed the LSTM with all *Filters* together concatenated horizontally.

I have seen some code that concat images horizontally something like :

```
images = encoded_imgs[0,:,:,:] // eg: first output of a CNN layer

print(images[1,1,:].size)

image=images[:,:,0]
for i in range(1,10):
    image=hstack((image,images[:,:,i]))
```

but how can I apply this to a lambda function to change my example to feed all into one `LSTM`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I manage to do this using merge concat axis 2 after lambda function to "individualize" every "filtered image"

```
        conv2=Conv2D(filters,(3,3), padding="same")(conv1)
        conv2=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 1), strides=(1, 1))(conv2)
        conv2=Activation("relu")(conv2)
        channels=Dropout(0.40)(conv2)
        filtersVec=[]
        for x in range(0,filters):
            filterImg=Lambda(lambda element : element[:,x,:,:])(channels)              
            filtersVec.append(filterImg)
        merged = merge(filtersVec, mode='concat',concat_axis=2)
        lstm=Bidirectional(LSTM(20),merge_mode='concat',dropout=0.35)(merged)
        classificationLayer=Dense(classes)(lstm)
        classificationLayer=Activation("softmax")(classificationLayer)
```